k-means clustering on a probability distribution instead of a dataset
Normally, clustering algorithms such as $k$-means are defined on a dataset in the following sense: if $D$ is a dataset, find a partition of $D$ into sets $\{S_1, \dots, S_n\}$ that minimises the within-cluster sum of squares given by $$\sum_{i=1}^n |S_i| \text{Var} (S_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{|S_i|} \sum_{x, y\in S_i}\lVert x-y\rVert.$$ I am wondering if it is possible to define a $k$-means algorithm with reference to a probability distribution $\mu$ instead of a dataset $D$. For example, suppose that our dataset simply consists of a collection of 2d points distributed according to the following probability distribution (where dark represents low probability):

Then if we use $k$-means clustering with 2 clusters, we will (most likely) get one cluster centered at -1, and the other at 1. I am wondering if we can just define the clustering algorithm on the distribution itself, and segment the input space into Voronoi cells without reference to a dataset. In other words, I would like to find two things: 1. an objective function $f$ that evaluates a given Voronoi partition of the input space with respect to a given distribution 2. a way of minimising this objective function for a given distribution.
I would like this to align with the $k$-means objective function in the following sense. Suppose we have IID random variables $Z_1, \dots, Z_m$ distributed according to $\mu$ such that $\{Z_1(\omega), \dots, Z_m(\omega)\}$ is a dataset distributed according to $\mu$ for any random outcome $\omega$. Then let $\mathcal{V}(\omega)$ be the Voronoi cell partition induced by the $k$-means algorithm on this dataset and let $SS(\omega)$ be the within cluster sum of squares for this partition on this dataset. Then I would like to have the property $$\mathbb{E}[f(\mathcal{V})] = \mathbb{E}[SS].$$
The purpose of this is to provide a way to quantify the suitability of $k$-means for a given theoretical input distribution. For example, to work out quantities like the expected sum of within cluster distances, and expected error rates if the clustering is made into a classification task.

Sorry,  but I don't see the point here. You have created, or are imagining, a set-up with two distinct clusters, but it's not clear to me in the absence of any key or legend whether all dark colours mean low densities -- or one colour means zero density. If k-means confirms what you did, then well and good, but what have you learned? If k-means doesn't, then it is useless for your purpose, but you could simulate and try for yourself to see if it "works". More generally, clustering a continuum of variation is often disappointing if not futile.

Hi Nick. Sorry for not adding a legend to this plot - the picture was not supposed to be precise, but simply an example for illustrative purposes. I am not so much trying to learn something about a given distribution, but instead say something about the suitability of k-means on that distribution. As you say, k means may or may not work for my distribution, and I would like to have a mathematical quantification of when it will or will not work. I am not quite sure what you mean by saying that clustering a continuum is often disappointing if not futile.

I thought $K$-means minimises the sum of squared distances from the corresponding cluster centers. Or is it equivalent to your definition?

Hi Igor. Yes, these definitions are equivalent according to the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

In that case, what's wrong with computing the variance over the Voronoi cells: $\sum_i \int_{V_i} (x-\mu_i)^2 f(x) dx$?

Clustering works best if there really are clear clusters. That may seem too banal or obvious to be worth saying, but I've seen far too many puzzled or disappointed or frustrated analysts wasting their time finding out that clustering doesn't really help -- including that different methods or choices give inconsistent results -- which is rarely surprising once you see plots of their data (or of two-dimensional reductions of their data) and see that variation is more nearly continuous.

Hi Nick. In some ways this is exactly my point as well - I am trying to work out if we can say theoretically when it will be the case that clustering will not work well for a given data distribution.

@IgorF. that sounds like a reasonable suggestion. I will try to investigate some of the consequences of this definition

I think this is a question that can't be answered to universal satisfaction. To some it will seem obvious that clustering won't tell you anything new, sceptics will demand that you try it out, and clustering enthusiasts will all be  suggesting their own favourite method as likely to work better. I doubt that there is a general theoretical argument independent of which clustering method you try or imagine.

Referring to k-means as an "algorithm" and to Voronoi cells suggests you are still thinking in terms of analyzing data.  For a general distribution, the k-means objective function can still be formulated, but most likely there won't be any general algorithm for optimizing it: it will depend on the distribution and how that distribution is represented.  Consequently it appears you are trying to ask about two different things: is this question about distributions or data? If about the latter, what's the problem with existing k-means algorithms?

@whuber I am asking about the former; I have a theoretical distribution, and I want to talk about the theoretically optimal value of some objective function on that distribution. You are exactly right that I don't really care about the algorithm for optimising the objective function, but only care about the objective function and the theoretical properties of that objective function.

If you wouldn't mind editing the post to include that clarification, I am confident you will quickly collect the votes to reopen it.

@whuber I edited the question but to be honest I think IgorF's simple solution is actually what I was looking for so we probably don't need to reopen the question.

Although Igor's approach is insightful, it doesn't look like a solution, because in k-means the $\mu_i$ must also be the barycenters of their cells.
